# A question about finding average velocity and average acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

I have trouble understanding the following problem's answer:

> *Which of the following relations are true for any arbitrary motion in space?*
>
> (a)   $v_{avg}=\frac{r(t_2)-r(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}$
>
> (b)   $v_{avg}=\frac{v(t_1)+v(t_2)}{2}$
>
> (c)   $a_{avg}=\frac{v(t_2)-v(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}$

Clearly b is wrong.

But my book says a and c are correct:

avg velocity=total distance by total time, so, how is the first part taking out total dist / total time? I would think

$$v_{avg}=\frac{v_1(t_1)+v_2(t_2)}{t_1+t_2}$$

and similarly for avg acceleration. Why isn't this the case?

Comment: The OP does show some effort, and does tell us the concept at which he or she is stuck.

Comment: Remember that $r(t_1)$ and $t_1$ are *coordinates*.

Comment: think units. $v(t_1)$ is velocity at time, $t_1$. So a velocity divided by a time can't give you a velocity.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55809/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are asking why you should use $t_2-t_1$ in the denominator instead of $t_2+t_1$.  The reason is that both measurements are taken with respect to some initial time.  This initial time is arbitrary; think about it as the time when you started your stopwatch.  The total time *elapsed* between the events occurring at $t_1$ and $t_2$ is therefore $t_2-t_1$.