# Derivation of the average Velocity formula with constant acceleration (using calculus)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

I have been looking at

$$
v_{avg} = \frac{v_{i} + v_{f}}{2},
$$

when the **acceleration is constant**, where $v_i$ is equal to the initial velocity and $v_f$ is equal to the final velocity.

How can you derive this using calculus?

$$
v_{avg} = \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} = \frac{1}{t_{f} - t_{i}} \int_{t_{i}}^{t_{f}} v(t) dt
$$

We know that

$$
v(t) = at + v_0,
$$

thus by substituting this into the previous integral yields

$$
v_{avg} = \frac{1}{t_{f} - t_{i}}  \left[a\frac{t_f^2}{2} + v_{0} t_f - a\frac{t_i^2}{2} - v_{0} t_i\right].
$$

But there's nothing else, which I can think of. Idea?

Comment: I have edited the maths to make it clearer, if you meant something else by your notation (or if you don't like the edit), you can roll back the changes.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55809/2451

Answer (score 1):

There is one error in the derivation, if you want to have $v(t_i)=v_0$, you must have
$$v(t) = v_0 + a(t-t_i)$$
You also have to use the fact that $v_f = v(t_f)$. Once you use all this, you should be able to divide out $t_f-t_i$ in the corrected version of your last line and get the result you seek.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done. If you simplify the express you found for $v_{avg}$ and compare it with the initial equation for $v_{avg}$, in which you have to substitute $v_i$ for $v(t_i)$ and $v_f$ for $v(t_f)$, you will see that they are equivalent.

Another way of deriving this is by expressing $v(t)$ in terms of $v_i$ and $v_f$:

$$
v(t) = v_i + \frac{v_f - v_i}{t_f - t_i} (t - t_i)
$$

Simplifying the resulting expression of the integral of this equation should also give you your initial equation for $v_{avg}$.